# Flickr OAuth from Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, flickr

I have a weird problem with Flickr OAuth on Google App Engine:

I'm requesting for oauth token and secret from Flickr using the code attached.. it fails most of time when tested on App Engine.. Flickr returns a page saying

**"Flickr has the hiccups. We're looking into the problem right now..."**

At first I thought it might be the problem with Flickr.. but then if I copied the URL into chrome directly, I could get the oauth token and secret..
So I thought it could be the problem with my code fetching the URL.. but in fact, with the same piece of code, I'm also able to get token and secret at **localhost**..

Now I'm really confused.. because this used to work perfectly until recently.. is there any update on App Engine dev server that might cause the problem? Please help!!!

```
        url = "http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token"
        params = {
            "oauth_timestamp": str(int(time())),
            "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1",
            "oauth_version": "1.0",
            "oauth_nonce": sha1(str(random())).hexdigest(),
            "oauth_callback": API_CALLBACK,
            "oauth_consumer_key": API_KEY,
        }
        # Setup the Consumer with the key-secret given by Flickr
        consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=API_KEY, secret=API_SECRET)

        # Create request
        req = oauth2.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params)

        # Create signature
        signature = oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1().sign(req, consumer, None)

        # Add the Signature to the request
        req['oauth_signature'] = signature

        h = httplib2.Http()
        resp, content = h.request(req.to_url(), "GET")
```

Update: I changed the code a little bit, keep requesting if I don't get the token (given a max try allowed). It works... still, it is very annoying that I have to write such work-around. Would appreciate if better alternative is available!

Comment: "It fails most of the time" Has it been working before?

Comment: yes. it was working previously... and now it may work after several attempts..

Comment: I log the req.to_url() and copy paste the url into Chrome, still be able to get the token.. don't know why it does not work from the direct request :(

Comment: Try using `urllib2`.It manages requests better most of the time.

Comment: can you give me example code? I tried result = urlfetch.fetch(url=req.to_url(), method=urlfetch.GET, deadline=90) no helps

Comment: tried urllib2.urlopen() no luck -.-

Comment: Try the latest development version of my FlickrAPI implementation, from https://bitbucket.org/sybren/flickrapi/. I could really use some testers & documentation writers before I actually release this code as "stable".

Comment: Thanks for offering that.. but I already have my own implementation and would appreciate more if someone could help me find the reason behind..

Comment: Would using https instead of http help?

Comment: I've had a similar problem when running a Java application on App Engine live - doesn't happen when running on the development server at localhost - where a simple flickr.photos.search API call randomly results in this _hiccups_ error.  I've now also done the retry hack, and it actually seems to solve the problem, but I feel equally annoyed that I had to go that route :)

Comment: @ZigMandel seems working with https. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use https instead of http (see the comment thread above)